# Codeigniter, Severity: error --> Exception: Too few arguments to function, admin dashboard shows HTTP error 500

Tags: php, function, codeigniter, model-view-controller

I am faced with an error in log files
This

`ERROR - 2022-05-13 02:47:21 --> Severity: error --> Exception: Too few arguments to function Transactions_model::get_pending_dash(), 0 passed in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/application/controllers/admin/Dashboard.php on line 47 and exactly 1 expected /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/application/models/Transactions_model.php 2134`

Here is exact code under controllers for dashboard.php on line 47:

`$transactions = $this->transactions_model->get_pending_dash();`

Here is exact code under transactions_model.php models :

```
  // total transactions ////////////////////////////////////////////
  function total_dash_transactions()
  {
    $s= $this->db->select("COUNT(*) as num")->get("transactions");
    $r = $s->row();
    if(isset($r->num)) return $r->num;
    return 0;

    return $result[0]->Transactions;
  }
    
    function get_pending_dash($user) 
    {
        $where = "status = '1' AND type = '2'";
        return $this->db->where($where)->order_by('id', 'DESC')->limit(20)->get("transactions");
    }
```

Comment: since you dont have param pass to the function named `get_pending_dash(param1)` but if it required a param, u can let it be null or empty value so that it dont affect other function as well.. Like `get_pending_dash($user = null)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because in your function get_pending_dash requires `$user` as a parameter, but based on your code also you did not use it so if you did not use the parameter just delete the `$user` like the code below.

```
function get_pending_dash() 
{
    $where = "status = '1' AND type = '2'";
    return $this->db->where($where)->order_by('id', 'DESC')->limit(20)->get("transactions");
}
```

Comment: This solved the issue. Thanks @Ainz
I was able to delete the $user in extra 4 models. Issue resolved